# How to space items evenly in a horizontal Silverlight Listbox

Tags: silverlight

In Silverlight, I have a Vertical ListBox that has a Horizontal ListBox for each item.  I want the items in the HorizontalListbox to space evenly across the width of the parent (Vertical) ListBox.  How can I do this?

```
   <ListBox x:Name="MachineListBox" Background="Green">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CoilList}" Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate                                >
                            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
                       <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock
                                    Text="{Binding Coil}"
                                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll take the liberty of suggesting you use a custom control of my own invention. It's called a ProportionalPanel and it does just what you need - spaces items evenly. You could use it for the ItemsPanel in the inner ListBox instead of the StackPanel. I also provide the source code, so you can tweak the logic any way you like. The relevant post on my blog is [here](http://itblobs.blogspot.com/2008/11/proportionalpanel-custom-control-for.html).

Comment: The ProportionalPanel link is now broken. Please update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proportional sizing operator will do what you're looking for. Haven't tried it but it sounds like an option. Width="`*" and Margin="2`*".